# Excel function to return values in Array1 but not in Array2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
Array1 = {1,2,3}
Array2 = {3,4,5}
```

What function will take these two arrays (as ranges on the worksheet) and return the values that appear in Array1 but not in Array2? In my example, the desired output is {1,2}.

Once I have this function, I want to use SMALL() to get the k smallest value.

Can built-in functions be used to do this in a single cell?

---

To clarify, here's a screenshot:

[image]

I'm looking for built in functions that can replace MYFUNC() and return {1,2} because they are in the first range but not the second. Combined with the SMALL() function, as in the screenshot, the result will be 1.

For comparison to SQL, this would be like:

```
SELECT number from Table1
WHERE number NOT IN
(SELECT number FROM Table2)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of sheet. Its not clear exactly what you want.

Comment: How are you using the two arrays to come to (1,2)? This question is very unclear.

Comment: Is this clear now with a screenshot and comparison to SQL. Or is there still something you see wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array version of `COUNTIF`:

```
=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(B4:D4,B2:D2)=0,B2:D2,""),k)
```

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in the formula to array enter it.

Where `k` is your `k`th.

Note: The array is also returning a blank `""`.

Comment: @Calvin Oops, I had a different range when I was testing it. Thanks for spotting it :)